# IronPDF: using ChromePdfRenderer.RenderUrlAsPdf

Tags: asp.net, ironpdf

I'm using the [ChromePdfRenderer.RenderUrlAsPdf method](https://ironpdf.com/object-reference/api/IronPdf.Rendering.Abstractions.BasePdfRenderer.html#IronPdf_Rendering_Abstractions_BasePdfRenderer_RenderUrlAsPdf_System_String_) to render a ASP.NET blazor page.

That page is using some internal methods from the model. When everything is good, it works fine.
The problem is that when any of those methods fails, the server returns an error page, with HTTP status code = 500 and IronPDF is generating the pdf with that error page in it. (Of course, that's what the url is returning)

My question: Is there a way of getting the HTTP status code that IronPDF is getting internally, so I can decide based on this, if the genrated PDF is valid or not?

Note: I know I could get the html from the url first, and then use the "RenderHtmlAsPdf" methods, but that's not the point.

Answer (score -1):

You need to code your method with `try{} catch{}` conditions with Exception Handler.

```
public async Task<PdfDocument> GenerateIronPDF(string Url)
{
    try
    {
         var Renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();
         Renderer.RenderingOptions.RenderDelay = 10000;
         var pdf = Renderer.RenderUrlAsPdf(Url);
         return pdf;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await _exceptionService.HandleException(ex, 
        $"YourSerService/GenerateIronPDF/pdf", string.Empty);
    }

}
```

Create another Service and call it ExceptionService

```
namespace Whatever.Services
{
    public class ExceptionService : IExceptionService
    {
        private ILogger<ExceptionService> _logger;

        public ExceptionService()
        {

        }

        public ExceptionService(ILogger<ExceptionService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task HandleException(HttpContext httpContext, Exception ex, LogLevel logLevel = LogLevel.Warning)
        {
            try
            {
                string absoluteUri = string.Concat(
                        httpContext.Request.Scheme,
                        "://",
                        httpContext.Request.Host.ToUriComponent(),
                        httpContext.Request.PathBase.ToUriComponent(),
                        httpContext.Request.Path.ToUriComponent(),
                        httpContext.Request.QueryString.ToUriComponent());
                string username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                await HandleException(ex, absoluteUri, username, logLevel);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }

        public async Task HandleException(Exception ex, string uri, string username, LogLevel logLevel = LogLevel.Warning)
        {
            try
            {
                string platform = "yourWeb.com";
                var sb = new StringBuilder().Append("<h2>Error Information</h2>");
                sb.Append("<p>Exception type: ").Append(ex.GetType()).Append("</p>");
                sb.Append("<p>Exception message: ").Append(ex.Message).Append("</p>");
                if (ex.InnerException != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ex.InnerException.Message))
                {
                    sb.Append("<p>Inner exception: ").Append(ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
                sb.Append("<p>Request Url: ").Append(uri).Append("</p>");
                sb.Append("<p>User: ").Append(username).Append("</p>");
                sb.Append("<p>Stack trace:</p><p>").Append(ex.StackTrace.Replace(" at", "<br/>at")).Append("</p>");
                if(_logger != null)
                {
                    _logger.Log(logLevel, sb.ToString());
                }
                if (!uri.Contains("localhost"))
                {
                    await RDS2.Shared.EmailService.SendEmailAsync("YourEmail@yahoo.com", "Error Handled on " + platform, sb.ToString());
                }
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public interface IExceptionService
    {
        Task HandleException(HttpContext httpContext, Exception ex, LogLevel logLevel = LogLevel.Warning);
        Task HandleException(Exception ex, string uri, string username, LogLevel logLevel = LogLevel.Warning);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope. There is no exception being raised, as the url is returning a valid html (but of course, with the http 500 error html page instead of mine)

Comment: Dear Juan, You mentioned "when any of those methods fails, the server returns an error page". Did you set any exception handler to catch the failed method? if Yes, it means your exception code is wrong. Lets assume your Exception handler catch a faulty method, then it should stops right away before going to GenerateToPdf method.